# Beautifulsoap.find_all won't parse this particular tag(html)

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse a html which look like this:

```
<tbody>
  <tr id="row1" class="background-off-white"></tr>
    <td id="column_packet_nm__1">Text to be captured #1</td>
  <tr id="row2" class="background-off-white"></tr>
    <td id="column_packet_nm__2">Text to be captured #2</td>
  <tr id="row3" class="background-off-white"></tr>
    <td id="column_packet_nm__3">Text to be captured #3</td>
</tbody>
```

with this code(python):

```
soup = bs(main_page, 'html.parser')
change = soup.find_all('td', {'id':'column_packet_nm__1'})
#print only first record among all, just for a confirmation
print(change[0].text)
```

but the problem is that, it gives me error everytime saying that 
"Exception has occurred: TypeError, object of type 'Response' has no len()"
and I am not sure this code will catch all those 3 lines,
Please help..

Comment: Are you calling `len(response)` somewhere?

Comment: There is some code you are not showing us. I get Text to be captured #1  with imports added. Can you show more code and url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure `main_page` is not a `Response` object (from requests). It should be the string text of the object.  It looks your `main_page` variable is a requests `Response` object.

So, if you have something like this somewhere:

```
main_page = requests.get(url)
```

You can use `.text`:

```
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(main_page.text, 'html.parser')
```